# Using Autowired in a TestExecutionListener class for BeforeClass junit

Tags: java, spring, junit, listener

I need to do a `@BeforeClass` method in junit but inject values using Spring so can't switch `private` variables to `static`. I am trying to do this Listeners and and creating a Listener class but I am running into an issue with this.

I have values that I need to `Autowire` in this class as well because the method I want to run `BeforeClass` calls for a variable that is `@Autowired` injected. However, for some reason, it is not working and this value remains null. Has anyone run into a problem like this before?

Comment: http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com/2012/09/enhancing-spring-test-framework-with.html http://www.tikalk.com/java/how-create-after-class-methods-junit-4-using-spring-3-framework

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza it's bad advice to mix test and AbstractTestExecutionListener in one class

Answer (score 19):

It's not the cleanest, but it works:

```
public class MyTestListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Value("${my.value}")
    private String myValue;
    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;

    @Override
    public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        testContext.getApplicationContext()
                .getAutowireCapableBeanFactory()
                .autowireBean(this);
    }
}
```