# @Autowired bean is null in Test Listener class

Tags: spring, unit-testing, autowired, spring-test

This question was asked before [Using Autowired in a TestExecutionListener class for BeforeClass junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21687022/using-autowired-in-a-testexecutionlistener-class-for-beforeclass-junit) however it wasn't answered. I am facing the same problem but haven't figured out the solution

Example: I am getting null mapper.

```
public class CustomExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {


@Autowired
private Mapper mapper;

@Override
public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) {}
... some code...
}
```

Test Class: Note: AppConfig contains the Mapper Bean defined.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, CustomExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppConfig.class})
public class AccountControllerTest {
....
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependency injection is not supported for `TestExecutionListener` instances.

Dependency injection is only supported for test instances.

Thus, if your `CustomExecutionListener` needs to access a bean from the `ApplicationContext`, it will have to look it up manually -- for example, like this:

```
public void beforeTestClass(TestContext testContext) {

    Mapper mapper = testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(Mapper.class);

    // ... some code...

}
```

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

Comment: I was actually do similar thing:


`AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = testContext.getApplicationContext().getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(this, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, false);
        beanFactory.initializeBean(this, this.getClass().getName());`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this: `Mapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(Mapper.class);`

Comment: An explanation will get noticed among viewers. and always try to write a descriptive answer.